# Register generic factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a `ICommand` and `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interfaces and need to inject factory:

```
public class CommandProcessor
{
    private readonly Func<Type, ICommandHandler<ICommand>> _handler;

    public CommandProcessor(Func<Type, ICommandHandler<ICommand>> handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }
}
```

To have an ability to do the following:

```
public void Process(ICommand command)
{
    var handler = _handler(command.GetType());

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.Handle(command);
    }

    throw ...
}
```

I tried to register the factory:

```
    builder.Register<Func<Type, ICommandHandler<ICommand>>>(context => type =>
        {
            var handlerType = context.Resolve(type);
            return (ICommandHandler<ICommand>) handlerType;
        });
```

But got the following exception:

The requested service 'QVocado.Commands.Information.PostProblemCommentCommand' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that your `CommandProcessor` is just a useless abstraction in your system. Instead of letting consumer depend on the `CommandProcessor`, let them depend directly on one or multiple closed versions of the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface. This solves your problem elegantly, because Autofac can resolve those dependencies for you. Besides, this prevents breaking the object/dependency graph into sub graphs (which is what happens when you use a factory) and this makes it much easier to verify your DI configuration.

Perhaps the reason that you introduced the `CommandProcessor` abstraction is because you would otherwise have to inject to many `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` dependencies into consumers. In that case you are probably violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and this leads to classes that are hard to maintain and hard to test.

Removing the `CommandProcessor` also removes the need to implement `ICommand` on each command message.

Note that the delegate you registered does not resolves a command handler, but simply a command. You will have create a closed generic version of the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface using `MakeGenericType` to do this. Here is the proper implementation:

```cs
builder.Register<Func<Type, ICommandHandler<ICommand>>>(
    context => commandType =>
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>)
            .MakeGenericType(commandType);
        var handler = context.Resolve(handlerType);
        return (ICommandHandler<ICommand>)handler;
    });
```